# @Encoding special characters in HTTP requests

Tags: c#, .net, api, salesforce, resharper

I'm trying to develop a console application to generate access token from Salesforce REST API using rest sharper library in C#. One of the request parameters is username which is of type user@username.com. I have tried to encode it. C# detects it the proper way after encoding it. But fiddler data is showing %20 instead of @ for username.

Appreciate your input.

```
namespace Restsharper
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://xx--zz.mm.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.POST };



        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-16");
        request.Parameters.Clear();
        request.AddParameter("grant_type","password");
        var pwd = Uri.EscapeUriString("Password#");
        var userName = Uri.EscapeUriString("user@username.com");
        request.AddParameter("password", pwd);
        request.AddParameter("username", userName);
        request.AddParameter("client_id","456fdas4fsdfsd4fds65uiryewiuryiuy43246FSDFSdasfcdasfasfFDF45_$rewrw#$$fFFFF");
        request.AddParameter("client_secret","77554698412");
        // request.RequestFormat("","");


        var response = client.Execute(request);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is it showing % instead of %20? Where should it appear? Why are you use this kind of authentication, including using and password in plain text?

Comment: for user name its showing user%20@username.com instead of user@username.com